# No sound output on Raspbian 4.4.210, Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi, raspbian, hdmi

The sound has stopped working completely on my Raspberry Pi 4. It's plugged into HDMI 0 into a TV. I've checked that the TV still plays sound. The sound will work with bluetooth devices only, but will not play through both HDMI 0 and the aux jack. The way I've been testing if the sound works is by using YouTube on Chromium and RetroPi.

As far as troubleshooting goes, I've went into config.txt and tried changing hmdi_group and hdmi_mode, and reinstalling the alsamixer and alsa-utils.

Ive also tried:

```
sudo amixer -c 0 cset numid=3 <n>
```

However when I tried:

```
cd /opt/vc/src/hello_pi
 make -C libs/ilclient
 make -C libs/vgfont
cd hello_audio
 make
 ./hello_audio.bin
```

This did work.

If anyone could help me with troubleshooting it would be very appreciated

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your speakers are unmuted and cranked to full. You may have to put your ear up to the speaker, as it may be very soft.
2. A thread on the Raspberry Pi Forums also mentions this issue: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=5062.

Try running these commands and see if anything plays.

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-utils
sudo modprobe snd_bcm2835
sudo aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've tried the edits to config.txt in the link you suggested but unfortunately im still getting no audio

Comment: Do your speakers work? Try with another device to make sure.

Comment: If you have a usb sound card, try seeing if that works.

Comment: I've tried the Raspberry Pi on a computer monitor which I know works in terms of sound - still nothing, unfortunately I don't have a USB sound card to try that either

Comment: Try This:
sudo apt-get install alsa-utils
sudo modprobe snd_bcm2835
sudo aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav

Comment: It says its playing WAVE at 48000Hz Mono, but still no sound from the monitor or headphone jack

Comment: Try a youtube vid, and try some headphones, it might be that it is outputting very high frequency sounds.

Comment: Also try doing: sudo apt-get update, and sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: Looks like adding `dtparam=audio=on` to `/boot/config.txt` does the same

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue.  An update fixed it for me.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

For me I found that Raspbian had switched from using hdmi to the jack for sound. This happened after I'd installed Synaptic Package Manager. You just right click the icon in the top right of the screen and select whatever you want.